# Hbase Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run quorum server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am not able to start Hbase, whenever i start i get only Hmaster and Hregionserver in jps. Hquorompeer keeps missing.I checked logs and i am getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run quorum server
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:454)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:409)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.runZKServer(HQuorumPeer.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to process transaction type: 1 error: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:153)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:417)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.processTransaction(FileTxnSnapLog.java:211)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:151)
```

Comment: Post the contents of your config files

Comment: which all files hbase-site.xml?

Comment: Go to HBASE_HOME/conf/ hbase-site.xml and hbase-default.xml

Answer (score 4):

The reason that you are encountering this error could be the data directory where Zookeeper stores snapshots and logs is corrupted.

In order to avoid the HQuorumpeer daemon to die out, you need to provide a path to a new directory where zookeeper can store its snapshots. To do this you need to add the following property in Hbase.site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>location of the newly created folder</value>
<description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
The directory where the snapshot is stored.
</description>
</property>
```

Comment: I deleted all the logs from the /tmp directory and this resolved my issue. Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: The Deletion of logs from zookeeper log directory works. Thanks user2567368

Answer (score 1):

the default path of "hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir" is /tmp/hbase-*/zookeeper(/tmp/hbase-hadoop/zookeeper), remove it and try to start zookeeper again

Answer (score 0):

Removing all files from ZooKeeper directory solved the issue. In my case

```
rm /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/*
```